# addEventListener только для кнопки вниз и вверх

Tags: javascript, html, css

всем привет. Как сделать в JavaScript метод addEventListener только для кнопки вниз и вверх отдельно? Событие keydown не подошло так как это для нажатия любой кнопки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// регистрируем слушатель нажатий клавиш глобально на окно (можно также на document или отдельные элементы)
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    // проверяем, является ли нажатая клавиша (event.key) стрелкой вверх "ArrowUp" или вниз "ArrowDown"
    if ( ["ArrowUp", "ArrowDown"].includes(event.key) ) {
        // Ваш код
    }
});
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin куда более развернутый? Я привел реализацию `addEventListener` для клавиш "Вверх" и "Вниз" как и спрашивает автор вопроса

Comment: я думаю, пояснения бы совсем не помешали. посмотрите на примеры высоко оцененных ответов: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aa

Comment: Спасибо большое, все ясно и понятно. Выручили